# How to load a partial view in a parent view using MVC5?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views, renderpartial

View Page:

```
       function test()
       {
            document.getElementById("testing").showModal();
       }
       <img src="~/images/test.png" onclick="test()" />  
       <dialog id="testing" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; ">@Html.ActionLink("test","Test","Home")</dialog>
```

Homecontroller:

```
      public ActionResult Test()
      {
          .....
        return PartialView(c);
      }
```

When i do this it redirect me to the next page  but i want this view as a popup on  the parent view . I have also used @Html.partial("Test") , It created this view as popup but doesn't performed the action means  it is not showing the results that i want on my popup .  can any one help  what should i do for generating this view as popup window in the parent view

Comment: Instead of `@Html.ActionLink(...)`, did you try `@Html.RenderAction("<ActionMethod>","<Controller>")`

Comment: @SivaGopal i have tried @Html.RenderAction"<ActionMethod>","<Controller>") but the problem with this is  that when i  load my page  the action executed but what i want is that  when i click a button then action result must execute and show the resluts in popup window. by using this it execute the action before clicking the button :(